# How to maintain multiple unique data for a single user for N number of users in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to develop a shopping site where I need to maintain data like "Add to Cart" and "Previous Orders" for a single user, for N number of users in a database. E.g. if there is a user named "Mark" and I need to store his 5 items previously added to cart and 4 items as previous order and there are say 100 users like him whose data I need to store, How should I solve this problem? I am using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the order history?

Comment: I don't want to remove order history. I want to keep it in another table

Answer (score 0):

Each user is assigned a unique ID (you can exploit MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` for this purpose when creating the table of users.

Then, for items the users select, you create another table including the User_ID (from the previous table), the Item_ID (from a similar table for items), the status (that would indicate the status of the item for the specific user) and an optional field that would contain the order number when the user places the order (for one or more items).

In summary, and since you are actually asking for help in designing your database, I would suggest you sit with a pencil and a piece of paper and make lists of informational elements that you need, marking the one-to-one relation between them (when applicable). This will (approximately) suggest what needs to be arrange in a record of a table (e.g. all the stable details of a user would normally go together into a single table).